# Can't Access my EF Model through The MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

I'm a beginner to asp.net MVC .

I try to use `EF code first` with `MVC` (`visual studio 2013`).so I have

- Domain Classes
- DataLayer(Context)
- MVC app

i have added two references of my `domain classes` and `DataLayer` to the MVC App

But when i add the first `Controller` i can't find any model class !! or db context !! even though i `Rebuild` My App and adding the exact connection string in `web.config`

[image]

**My DBContext:**

```
public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public Context()
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Alias> Aliases { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Tweet> Tweets { get; set; }
        //.........................
    }
```

Comment: Can u show your classes `Domain Class` and `DbContext` class.

Comment: @MairajAhmad : i edit my question with part of my db context,`my domain classes` are just classes no thing special about them

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me before, try closing your solution and re-opening it.  Run clean solution then run build solution.  Then try to add the controller again.  It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy-peasy.

Just right-click, add class (if you don't see ADO.NET Entity Model as an entry, this is the way to find it) then add the entry ADO.NET Entity Model. Then, once you regen your edmx, simply add as a new Web API (or MVC) controller, (I did Web API because that is what I was working on) and make sure to select the Entity Framework version of the controller.

It will ask you for your model. Select the model name of the EDMX you just generated. It should populate the rest. Bam. You're done.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `New Controller` like this.

> - Right click on `Controllers` folder. Select `Add`.
> - Select `Controller`.
> - Select MVC 5 `Controller` with `view`, using `Entity Framework`.

OR

> - Right click on `Controllers` folder. Select `Add`.
> - Select `New Scaffolded Item`.
> - Select MVC 5 `Controller` with `view`, using`Entity Framework`.